# How to deal with an underperforming engineering manager at a startup?

Tags: management, team, startup

I'm at a startup that was an amazing place to work before we hired a new manager last year. In the time since morale has dipped drastically and amazing engineers feel they can no longer affect the product because of poor prioritization and delegation. I have not vented to anyone, but the team's public response to the manager shows lack of respect and trust. I have also had one person vent to me about the manager and several others about morale. Reasons for the decline include not celebrating effort or results, joking / insulting employees in demos and meetings, and a general lack of passion, integrity, and decision making.

The question is how to deal with a manager at a startup who is so crucial to the success of the company at such an early stage.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to organize as a group is risky. You could create drama that you cannot reverse (like when some people go along with it and some don't). If you are comfortable going to a company leader (and you trust him or her), you could say something like:  "I am not sure you are aware, so I wanted you to know that morale has dropped since Manager joined the team. He has made fun of people in meetings (give example), he insulted Bob in the middle of his demo, and we no longer seem to celebrate any of our good results, like X. I know you have good reasons for hiring Manager, but I thought you would want to know that people are starting to complain."  Then let it go. Don't wait for a response or explanation.

Don't assume the leaders know - often they don't, or maybe they have heard one complaint, and now they are hearing another. Don't expect the leaders to do anything in your presence except listen and maybe ask questions. They might try to defend him or their decision to hire. Just nod. Your goal is to be heard. It's up to them what comes next, and that part is between them and this Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Complain about the manager as a group.

Lay out the issues the group has with a manager in writing - The laying out of these issues could serve as a road map for the manager to improve. Or else.

Stick to the facts when you lay out the issues and damn the manager using the facts and not much more. Editorializing about the manager has the effect of reducing the legitimacy of your complaints to a matter of opinion - that would be the break that your belaguered manager would be looking for and the straw he'd be trying to grasp. A dispassionate but damning narrative is what you are looking for.